# Adding multiple conditions within a Link in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a Link in React that I need to add some conditions to but I'm not entirely sure how to do it. Below is some code that I am adapting and i need to use this formatting, I unfortunately cannot change the setup to pass some other props instead.

I've added comments to what I am trying to achieve below:

```
const isPageOne = location?.pathname?.includes('one')
const isPageTwo = location?.pathname?.includes('two')

<Link 
href={
 !isPageOne
 ? data.nav_booking?.link_url
 : isPageTwo ? `#` // Want to change href to # if isPageTwo - added this but it doesnt seem to work
 : `mailto:${data.nav_enquiry?.email}`
       }
                
target={`_blank`}
// Want to add an if isPageTwo then add an onlick=xxx
>
                
<span>
{!isPageOne && !isPageTwo && data.nav_booking?.link_text}
{isPageOne && data.nav_enquiry?.link_text}
{isPageTwo && data.nav_enquiry?.link_text} // Want to change the link_text to display some other text - no idea where link_text even pulls from
</span>

</Link>
```

I tried to alter a few things such as adding/changing the below lines but none of it has so far worked.

```
{isPageTwo && data.nav_enquiry?.`Some Text`}
```

If anyone could shed some light that would be great!

Comment: Calculate these things outside the Link and just pass the concrete things to Link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the conditional operation outside.

```
let link = `mailto:${data.nav_enquiry?.email}`
if(!pageOne){
 link = data.nav_booking?.link_url
} else if(pageTwo){
 link = "#"
}
```

And render it as:

```
<Link 
href={link}             
target={`_blank`}
>
```

Comment: Amazing! This was perfect, and so simple. The only thing I cant quite figure out now is the onclick one, as I only want onclick="" added if isPageTwo

Comment: @Kiki Simply add `onClick={isPageTwo? "" : clickHandler}`

Comment: Thanks so much! Seems i must have some other issue in the way as the onclick isn't working at all, ill debug. Thanks for your help!